# Mapbox React queryTerrainElevation returns null

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl

I am attempting to get the elevation of certain coordinates on the map using mapbox.
Based on the documentation, i can use [queryTerrainElevation](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/guides/access-elevation-data/).

Sample Code:

```
map.on("click", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  const elevation = map?.queryTerrainElevation(data.lngLat, {
    exaggerated: true,
  });
  console.log("Elevation: " + elevation)
});
```

Console logs:

[image]

Using the mapbox tilequery with the same coordinates:

```
 https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2/tilequery/95.9345,41.2565.json?access_token=<mapbox_token>
```

There is an elevation value in the response:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must be adding the custom layer after just loading the style. So, the terrain value isn't updated at that time. That's why you get null.
Do it like this and it should work.

```
 map.on('idle', () => {
const elevation = map.queryTerrainElevation(coordinates, {exaggerated: false});         
 })
```

This runs the layer code after the map is loaded. Instead of just the style.

Comment: This is how I initialize the map:
    
    `map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map-container",
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9",
        center: [mapCenter.coordinates.lng, mapCenter.coordinates.lat],
        zoom: mapCenter.zoom,
    });
    
    map.current?.on('load', () => {
        const elevation = map.current?.queryTerrainElevation(mapCenter.coordinates, {
        exaggerated: false,
    });
        
    console.log("elevation-VALUE", elevation);
    })`

Comment: unfortunately the elevation value is still null

Comment: Then I think you should use 'idle' instead of 'load'. I edited my answer. Try it and let me know if it works.